# How to terminate a for loop with if statement inside a do-while loop in c++?

Tags: c++

Inside a do-while loop I am reading values of a vector using for loop. This vector has repetitive values. I want to stop the for loop using if statement.

```css
do {
   /* some statement1*/
     for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
       {
         if (vec[i] == a)
           {
            /* some statement2*/
           }  
       } //here i want to terminate the for loop once it finds value a in vector 
   } while (statement3);
```

I used break; but it terminates the while condition also.

Comment: You could use a lambda and immediately call it, then use `return` as the `break`.

Comment: Looks like you're missing some pieces. Please provide a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think you misinterpreted what the break keyword does -- break will only break you out of the innermost loop that it is most directly inside of; it won't break you out of multiple layers of loops.

Comment: It is gross, but I am pretty sure it is legit to say i=n, assuming there is nothing more happening after the for loop but in the while loop\

Comment: Your `do..while` is missing a `;`

Comment: *"I used break; but it terminates the while condition also."* Can you show how and where in the code did you use `break`?

Comment: Please read [mcve] .  In following that, you would have seen that break; in fact only ends the innermost loop or case.  It's also never too late to read [tour] and [ask] .

Comment: @JeremyKahan But `i` will go out of scope once `for` ends

Comment: after /* some statement2*/ use break;

Comment: @cincout why would that be undesirable? The desired behavior is to get out of for, which will happen, but not out of while. At any rate, the style of the answers is much cleaner than my suggestion.

Comment: @JeremyKahan But there is no `i` after the `for` loop.

Comment: @CinCout that should be fine. I was suggesting setting I within the for loop, which will get you out when it next checks the condition at the top of the for loop, where i is in scope

Comment: Ah okay. @JeremyKahan

Answer (score 2):

Your code has multiple syntax errors i.e. missing closing braces for inner loop / if condition. There's only one closing brace. Here's the correct version of your code with `break` where it should be:

```
do
{
    /* some statement 1 */
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
    {
        if ( vec[i] == a )
        {
            /* some statement 2 */
            break;
        }
    }

} while ( condition );
```

And, it should work. It'll `break` the inner `for` loop only -- not the outer `do-while`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `break` Like this:

```
do {
  /* some statement1*/
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
    if (vec[i] == a) {
      break;
    }
  } 
} while (statement3);
```